# Using polymorphism/inheritance to refactor nested if statements into classes in python

Tags: python

There are several examples online in which `if...else` statements are replaced by constructs that use polymorphism/inheritance. [This link](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-avoid-large-if-else-trees) shows something similar to what I would like to achieve. I have a nested structure as follows:

```
def wishthiswouldbeobjectoriented(figuretype, randomtype):
  if figuretype=='list':
      # do some stuff and return a list
      out = 'figure type is list'
  elif figuretype=='random':
      if randomtype=='all':
          out = 'figure type is random and randomtype is all'
      elif randomtype=='selection':
          out = 'figure type is random and randomtype is selection'
  return out

if __name__ == '__main__':
  figuretype = 'random'
  randomtype = 'selection'
  print(wishthiswouldbeobjectoriented(figuretype, randomtype))
```

I'm guessing there should be a way to use polymorphism/inheritance to turn this into object-oriented code. Would anyone please provide a short, concise example in `python` which demonstrates how the above code could be converted into object oriented code?

Comment: Polymorphism implies that the concrete type does not matter - that one can substitute one for the other. Yet all of your paths have different signatures, meaning that they are not substitutable. Is there any technical reason why you see the need to use polymorphism?

Comment: Is there anything I can do to make this question more clear?

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? What problems did you encounter when converting your code to OOP design?

Comment: I need to convert the nested if statement into a construct which implements python classes. This link shows an example where this is done (https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-avoid-large-if-else-trees). The nested tree is very similar to mine. I did not yet try to convert it into OOP since I conceptually don't know how I would go about doing that. I'd have to learn the language used in the link in that example, compile and run it, debug it and see how I can convert it into python code. That's a lot of work, and the question is more conceptual..

Comment: This is very much possible. But it is unclear what you need to understand to do it yourself.

Comment: *"Is there anything I can do to make this question more clear?"*: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @stovfl Please see edited question. Instead of using pseudocode I now have a minimal working code.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi To undersand it I would need to see an example of how it could be done, which is why I am asking the question.

Comment: Essentially, you're looking for the Python equivalent of JS Prototypes? Do I understand correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Commen**: How would I from the text file know which object to instantiate,

Add the following:

```
class FigureFactory:
    def __new__(cls, args, **kwargs):
        # Mapping Type Keywords to real Class Definition
        figures = {('list',): FigureList,
                   ('random', 'all'): FigureRandomAll,
                   ('random', 'selection'): FigureRandomSelection
                   }
        figure = figures.get(args)
        if not figure:
            figure = Figure

        return figure(*kwargs['kwargs'])
```

Extend the following:

```
class Figure:
    ...

    @property
    def out_list(self):
        return "Invalid Type"

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} df={}'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.df)


class FigureRandom(Figure):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} n_value={}'.format(super().__str__(), self.n_value)
```

> Usage: **Note**: Invalid Type `list all`!

```
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    ...

    for cfg in [(('list',), (df,)), 
                (('random', 'all'), (df, n_points)),
                (('random', 'selection'), (df, n_accepted + 1)), 
                (('list', 'all'), (df,))]:
        figure = FigureFactory(args=cfg[0], kwargs=cfg[1])
        print('{} {}'.format(figure, figure.out_list))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> FigureList df=None figure type is list
> FigureRandomAll df=None n_value=1 figure type is random and randomtype is all
> FigureRandomSelection df=None n_value=2 figure type is random and randomtype is selection
> Figure df=None Invalid Type
> ```

---

> **Question**: refactor nested if statements into classes in python

```
class Figure:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    @property
    def out_list(self):
        return None


class FigureList(Figure):
    def __init__(self, df):
        super().__init__(df)

    @property
    def out_list(self):
        return 'figure type is list'


class FigureRandom(Figure):
    def __init__(self, df, n_value):
        super().__init__(df)
        self.n_value = n_value


class FigureRandomAll(FigureRandom):
    def __init__(self, df, n_points):
        super().__init__(df, n_points)

    @property
    def out_list(self):
        return 'figure type is random and randomtype is all'


class FigureRandomSelection(FigureRandom):
    def __init__(self, df, n_accepted):
        super().__init__(df, n_accepted)

    @property
    def out_list(self):
        return 'figure type is random and randomtype is selection'
```

> Usage:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    df = None
    n_points = 1
    n_accepted = 1

    for figure in [FigureList(df), FigureRandomAll(df, n_points), FigureRandomSelection(df, n_accepted)]:
        print('{}'.format(figure.out_list))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> figure type is list
> figure type is random and randomtype is all
> figure type is random and randomtype is selection
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What's the @property decorator for? Is it really necessary here? Does it actually do anything?

Comment: *"Is it really necessary here?"*: No, without you have to use `figure.out_list()`, note the `()`. Read [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What follows is purely a mechanical exercise in using inheritance as the dispatch method rather than a series of explicit `if` statements. Rather than passing `figure` and `randomtype` as arguments to a function, the choices are implicitly encoded in the class itself.

```
class Figure:
    def wishthiswouldbeobjectoriented(self):
        pass


class FigureList(Figure):
    def wishthiswouldbeobjectoriented(self):
        return "figure type is list"


class FigureRandom(Figure):
    pass


class FigureRandomAll(FigureRandom):
    def wishthiswouldbeobjectoriented(self):
        return 'figure type is random and randomtype is all'


class FigureRandomSelection(FigureRandom):
    def wishthiswouldbeobjectoriented(self):
        return 'figure type is random and randomtype is selection'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = FigureRandomSelection()
    print(f.wishthiswouldbeobjectoriented())
```

Comment: This answer implements a similar strategy as @stovfl's answer, right? I accepted that answer but I also really like this one. I'm just curious, is there really no other way than implementing a new class for each nested if? What design pattern is this formally called?

Comment: Not being a C++ or Java programmer, I'm not really familiar with the intricacies of most design patterns, since most of them seem to work around the lack of things like first-class function objects. I would just call this "polymorphism", as the behavior of `wishthiswouldbeobjectoriented` is completely determined by the type of the object invoking it. What this leaves out, though, is how you determine which class to instantiate in the first place. In some sense, you don't get rid of conditionals so much as "shift" where they occur.

Comment: The class is instantiated through user input in a simple input text file with `ConfigObj` library to parse arguments into a dict. The dict contains variables `figuretype`, `randomtype` and other variables which will be needed in the various `wishthiswouldbeobjectoriented` implementations. As you can imagine it is highly irritating to me that these can all be defined haphazardly in the text file by a user when in fact they are part of a well-defined nested if structure.

Comment: I wanted to come up with an 'architecture' which is somehow aware of the nesting of the if tree, and which would reject combinations that won't lead to anywhere in the tree. For instance, user input of `figuretype='list'` and `randomtype='all'`  is invalid input since it doesn't lead to anywhere in the tree in my minimal working example. However, it's still possible, and won't crash the program, leading to incorrect results and a happy user. I need the program to crash in case the user input is incorrect.... This last point however is still not solved by the object oriented paradigm either...

Comment: @user32882: *"haphazardly in the text file"*: The benefit of using `object` is you can implement parameter validation at a object type basis. E.g. `FigureRandomAll` knows which parameter needed.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean ... How would I from the text file know which object to instantiate, if its not using an additional equally convoluted nested if structure where I am doing object instantiations instead of actual processing? Same problem...

Comment: @user32882 At this point, you really need a new question that more precisely shows the input you are dealing with. This question was really probably too broad, but I thought an equally broad example solution was worth posting.

Comment: Yeah, you've got a point. I'll make a new question then...